# How to perform validation on a comparator passed by a method in java...?

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I am invoking a method by passing comparator like below:

```
treeSetDemo(null);
treeSetDemo(new PubDateAscComparator());
treeSetDemo(new PubDateDescComparator());
```

Basically, I am trying to sort objects based on the input given by the `treeSetDemo` method and here I am using book objects and sorting them by the publication year.

Now the `treeSetDemo` method takes a comparator as argument, as below:

```
public static Set<Book> treeSetDemo(Comparator comparator)
```

In the method definition, I want to perform actions based on which parameter is passed, like the example below:

```
if(comparator == PubDateAscComparator())
{
    Set<Book> books = new TreeSet<>(new PubDateAscComparator());
}
else if(comparator == PubDateDescComparator())
{
    Set<Book> books = new TreeSet<>(new PubDateDescComparator());`
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work...what should be written in the `if` statement to make this possible?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do. Why not just unconditionally set `Set<Book> books = new TreeSet<>(comparator)`? Isn't that the whole point of passing in the object to begin with?

Comment: What is `if(comparator == PubDateAscComparator())` supposed to mean? It looks invalid.

Comment: What Mad Physicist said.  The whole point of polymorphism is that no matter what implementation of Comparator you pass to your treeSetDemo method, the method can safely treat it as a Comparator.  You need not and should not check which specific type of Comparator was passed in.